# An integer won't double past a random number

Tags: c++

I have recently started learning C++ and have made this small program

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout << / std::cin >> / std::endl; / '\n'
#include <cstdlib>  // for EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE


int input()
{
    int imp_num{ 0 };
    std::cin >> imp_num;
    return imp_num;
}
void output(int result)
{
    std::cout << "The dubble of that number is : " << result  << '\n';
}
int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int inp_num{ input() };      // asks the user to enter a number and saves it 
    int result{ inp_num * 2 };   // calculates the result 
    output(result);              // outputs the result


    system("pause");             //prevents the console from terminating
    return 0;
}
```

The problem occurs when the number revived is 10 digits or more. At that point the program just a random number (usually -2) that will always remain the same no matter what I put, and only changes if I recompile the  source code.

```
Enter a number: 23213231231231212312
The dubble of that number is : -2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

```
Enter a number: 12311111111111111111111111
The dubble of that number is : -2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I recompile the source code

```
Enter a number: 1231212123133333333333321
The dubble of that number is : 3259
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Changing all the `int` to `int64_t` doesn't solve the problem but weirdly the same output of -2 is present here.

```
Enter a number: 1231212123133333333333321
The dubble of that number is : -2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't understand why out off all the numbers -2 will appear if an integer overflow is happening. I thought the numbers should circle around.

Comment: Try using int64_t, as int will be too small.

Comment: Same problem, same integer that appears.

Comment: Do you know that `int` can represent only a finite range of numbers?

Comment: Signed 32-bit `int` range is `-2147483648  to  2147483647` and for signed 64-bit you have `-9.2234e+18  to  9.2234e+18` -- you have way more than 19 digits.

Comment: Yes but aren't they supposed to loop around, lets say an integer can only hold a maximum number of 9 and the user enters a 13 shouldn't the integer hold 4? Since it counted to 9 and then went to zero and only when it reaches a 4 there is nothing more to count. But my confusion stand with the number -2. I have no idea why out of all the numbers It is this one that the program has stooped on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2019 Refer this link to understand what can and cannot be represented.

Comment: @IanisDonica "aren't they supposed to loop around" - wraparound on overflow is only defined for *unsigned* integer types. Overflow of a *signed* integer is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: What you should be doing is checking the result of `std::cin >> imp_num;`. Replace that line with `std::cout << !!(std::cin >> imp_num) << std::endl;` and check the output.

Comment: @Evg thank for the code line. I will use it in the future when dealing with large intigers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  Signed overflow is undefined, not implementation-defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson - thank you. Signed overflows is undefined,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value 1231212123133333333333321 given by you is drastically larger than even `uint64_t` could hold (overflows). In my case, the maximum range of a `uint64_t` (occupies 8-bytes data) datatype is:

```
0 to +18446744073709551615
```

To know the limits in your platform, i.e. practically, take a little bit help of C++ library `limits`:

```
#include <limits>
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() << std::endl;
```

Notice that it may vary on different computer architectures.

Answer (score -1):

`int`, which is a signed (usually 32 bit) number can only hold numbers from -2147483648 to 2147483647. When you're trying to input such a big number, `std::cin` fails to do so, an instead sets maximum possible value.

Now, you're trying to multiply biggest possible value to hold by 2, it causes an overflow and UB, technically anything can happen in your code, but what seems to be happening with the compiler you're using is the following.

`int` is 2 complement, it means that the biggest value has the following bit representation.

01111111111111111111111111111111, or 0x7fffffff in hex

When you're trying to multiply by 2, you're doing a left shit  by 1 bit and you get

11111111111111111111111111111110, or 0xfffffffe which represents -2.

Remember though that even if it happens with the compiler and flags/optimization you're using right now, using different compiler and flags can produce different results, as you're causing Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining, I was using a compiler by the name of  G++.